# How do i export my own angular component and the same can be imported in another project

Tags: angular, angular8

Am looking to put all the shared components in one project and using those components in another projects.

For Ex,

I have my own `rw-date-component`, which gets date range from user and performs validation based on my business logic.

Now i wanted such `rw-date-component` in **Project-1, Project-2, Project-3, etc...**

How do i export `rw-date-component` and use it in another project ?

Comment: create a [library](https://angular.io/guide/creating-libraries), and then use it in other projects

Comment: Also look into [Angular Elements](https://angular.io/guide/elements).

Comment: https://medium.com/@nikolasleblanc/building-an-angular-4-component-library-with-the-angular-cli-and-ng-packagr-53b2ade0701e

Comment: thanks all got an idea todo that :-)

Comment: A quick question of angular libraries. Angular libraries has version control ?